# How can I merge multiple csv files with Python as I want?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, row

I have a few csv files for my homework. I want to combine them as in the example below. But I didn't know how to do it.

Exp1.csv

```
"DATE","NOW","OPEN","HIGH","LOW","Hac.","VOL %"
"01.09.2019","23,78","25,54","25,54","23,78","-","-7,04%"
"25.08.2019","25,58","23,96","26,00","23,56","2,14M","4,07%"
```

Exp2.csv

```
"DATE","NOW","OPEN","HIGH","LOW","Hac.","VOL %"
"01.09.2019","4,16","4,15","4,23","4,12","-","0,73%"
"25.08.2019","4,13","4,05","4,19","4,03","6,48M","1,98%"
```

I want to merge 2 files like this. I just want to get the VOL% column.

```
"DATE","Exp1","Exp2"
"01.09.2019","-7,04%","0,73%"
"25.08.2019","4,07%","1,98%"
```

Thank you everyone:) I found a solution like this and applied it.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas.io

path =r'/Users/baris/Documents/Files/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pandas.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
concatenated_df = pandas.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1)
concatenated_df_clean = (concatenated_df.drop('DATE',1).drop('NOW',1).drop('OPEN',1).drop('HIGH.',1).drop('Low',1).drop('Hac.',1)

df_dates_file = pandas.read_csv('/Users/baris/Documents/Files/Exp1.csv')
df_date_export = concatenated_df.iloc[:, 0]

final_result = pandas.concat([df_date_export,concatenated_df_clean], axis=1)
print(final_result)
```

Comment: Is `VOL %` always going to be the 7th column?

Comment: Yeah, it's always in column 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('Exp1.csv', 'r') as f1:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
    lines1 = [row for row in csv_reader]

with open('Exp2.csv', 'r') as f2:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
    lines2 = [row for row in csv_reader]

del lines1[0]
del lines2[0]
with open('output.csv', 'w+') as output_file:
    output_file.write('"DATE","Exp1","Exp2"\n')
    for index, _ in enumerate(lines1):
        date = lines1[index][0]
        vol1 = lines1[index][6]
        vol2 = lines2[index][6]
        output_file.write(f'"{date}","{vol1}","{vol2}"\n')
```

This assumes the following:

- `VOL %` is always going to be in the 7th column (like in your example)
- `DATE` is always going to be in the 1st column (like in your example)
- there will always be the same number of lines in `Exp1.csv` and `Exp2.csv`
- the `"DATE"` will always be the same in `Exp1.csv` and `Exp2.csv`

Read more about the CSV module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I have 100 .csv files. This way not good for me but i saved your code for my other project. Thank you :)

Comment: @BarisOZER No worries, happy to help. If you see value in my answer, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas package to read and save csv.
However you cannot remove columns while merging the csv files, but you can save the columns that you need
Have a look at my code below.
Replace the csv filename and column name with yours.

```
import pandas as pd

# create list of files you want to merge
all_filenames = ['test.csv','test1.csv']

# use pandas concat function to merge csv's
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])

# export the csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig',columns=['test1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Exp1.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv('Exp2.csv')

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

final_df = pd.merge(df[['DATE', 'VOL %']], df1[['DATE', 'VOL %']], on='DATE')

print(final_df)
      DATE VOL %_x VOL %_y
2019-01-09  -7,04%   0,73%
2019-08-25   4,07%   1,98%
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the csv module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

read this tutorial:

https://realpython.com/python-csv/

something like this will do the work: (educational code)

```py
import io
import csv

target = {}

file_one_string =\
""""DATE","NOW","OPEN","HIGH","LOW","Hac.","VOL %"
"01.09.2019","23,78","25,54","25,54","23,78","-","-7,04%"
"25.08.2019","25,58","23,96","26,00","23,56","2,14M","4,07%"
"""
file_two_string = \
""""DATE","NOW","OPEN","HIGH","LOW","Hac.","VOL %"
"01.09.2019","4,16","4,15","4,23","4,12","-","0,73%"
"25.08.2019","4,13","4,05","4,19","4,03","6,48M","1,98%"
"""


with io.StringIO(file_one_string) as file_one:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_one,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if 'VOL %' in row:
            target[row['DATE']] ={'Exp1': row['VOL %']}

with io.StringIO(file_two_string) as file_two:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_two,dialect="excel")
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row['DATE'] in target:
            target[row['DATE']]['Exp2'] = row['VOL %']
        else:
            print('Missing DATE {} in file_two'.format(row['DATE']))
    lines2 = [row for row in csv_reader]


with io.StringIO() as output_file:
    fieldnames = ['DATE', 'Exp1', 'Exp2']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for key, value in target.items():
        csv_writer.writerow({
            'DATE': key,
            'Exp1': value['Exp1'],
            'Exp2': value['Exp2']
        })

    print(output_file.getvalue())
```